# WPF Telerik gridview click events

Tags: wpf, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a telerik gridview that I need to add both a single click and double click event. Basically the user can click a row once for a distinct event and then can also double click for a different event.

Initially I was using the SelectionChanged event to differentiate the two... but now I am having issues with anytime anything changes on the page, this event is fired.

If I implement a single click (MouseDown) event and a MouseDoubleClick event. The single click always overrides the double click and it cannot distinguish between the two - thus never making it to the double click event.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MVVM, you would probably prefer to attach an ICommand, which will be passed the DataContext of the row that has been clicked on, as a parameter.

Comment: @MikeSchwartz did this help? If so, please mark it as the answer. If not, perhaps give your solution, or clarify why it didn't help.